# What is the best way to build a package that targets a single Ubuntu release only?

Tags: package-management, dpkg, packaging, debian

At the moment I build and package our software for Ubuntu 14.04 aka 'trusty' via `dpkg-buildpackage`. I get a `.deb` package that can be installed on Ubuntu 14.04 but also on other Ubuntu releases e.g. 12.04 aka 'precise'. This is dangerous as the software can be installed without error message but the program is unable to run/work correctly.

Dependencies of my package are given in the `control` file. However this file does not let me enter a distribution/codename of Ubuntu. The distribution may be entered as part of the `*.changes` but this is not reflected anywhere in the .deb file. Checking the complex dependency situation during the post-install script is complex too. Thus I want an easy way to prevent an installation of an Ubuntu package on the wrong Ubuntu release.

What is the best way to build a package that targets a single Ubuntu release only? In the best case (1) the installation should only work on the targeted Ubuntu release and (2) the `.deb` package contains the distribution name*, e.g. like `package_1.0.0-3_trusty_amd64.deb`.

(*) Otherwise the apt repository managed via `reprepro`cannot have two packages with the same version number, each targeting a different Ubuntur release.

Thanks in advance.

**Update:**

The `debian/control` file of my package:

```
Source: mypackage
Priority: extra
Build-Depends: debhelper (>= 9), python (>=2.7), pyside-tools
X-Python-Version: >= 2.7
Standards-Version: 3.9.2

Package: mypackage
Architecture: amd64
Depends: ros-indigo-desktop-full|ros-hydro-desktop-full, ros-indigo-rqt|ros-hydro-rqt, ros-indigo-gps-umd|ros-hydro-gps-umd, ros-indigo-map-server|ros-hydro-map-server, imagemagick, octave (>= 3.6), libdc1394-22, sox, tree, python (>=2.7), python-psutil, python-usb, python-serial, python-gi, gir1.2-gexiv2-0.10|gir1.2-gexiv2-0.4, exfat-fuse|fuse-exfat, exfat-utils, gphotofs, python-pyproj, libusb-1.0-0 (>=2:1.0.17), libpyside1.2|libpyside1.1 (>=1.1.2), ${shlibs:Depends}, ${misc:Depends}
Description: ...
```

As one can see this control file was adapted such that we can run the build on multiple Ubuntu releases where the dependencies have different version numbers: `libpyside1.2|libpyside1.1 (>=1.1.2)`. Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: I added the content of the control file. Is there a better way to handle builds for multiple Ubuntu releases?

Comment: If you want to have a single `debian` folder for all releases, then that would be the only way (unless you have a script that changes the dependencies for each particular version). Alternatively, you can have a `debian` folder (or, for this case, a `debian/control` file) for each separate version.

Comment: I get it. However, how can I start the build chain with different `debian/`directories or different `control` files? I have not found a command line option that allows `dpkg-buildpackge` to use a different directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Because, your package is installed in release/environment that it will not able to work in, That means your packages `control` dependencies missing something.

  What I expect that you haven't put dependencies version conditions, which could used to let package to be installed on single release if the dependency version available only in that release, example gedit: `gedit-common (>= 3.10), gedit-common (<< 3.11)`

  ```
  Depends: libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libc6 (>= 2.14), libcairo2 (>= 1.2.4), libenchant1c2a (>= 1.6.0), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libgirepository-1.0-1 (>= 0.9.3), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.38), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.10), libgtksourceview-3.0-1 (>= 3.10.0), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libpeas-1.0-0 (>= 1.1.0), libx11-6, libxml2 (>= 2.7.4), libzeitgeist-2.0-0 (>= 0.9.9), gedit-common (>= 3.10), gedit-common (<< 3.11), gsettings-desktop-schemas, python3-gi (>= 3.0), python-gi-cairo (>= 3.0), gir1.2-peas-1.0, iso-codes
  Recommends: gir1.2-gtksource-3.0, zenity, yelp
  Suggests: gedit-plugins
  Breaks: gedit-plugins (<< 2.91)
  ```

  Reference: [Debian Policy Manual: Chapter 7 - Declaring relationships between packages](https://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-relationships.html)
- Another way using `preinst`  script and `lsb_release` command:

  ```
  #!/bin/sh
  set -e 

  release=$(lsb_release -cs)
  if [ ! "$release" = "trusty" ]
  then
      echo "This packages wasn't build for your release."
      echo "Package wasn't installed, See ..."
      exit 1
  fi

  exit 0
  ```

  If you want `trusty` to be defined while build you can make a template as `preinst.in` and write a makefile to do variable substitution while building source.

Comment: Thanks, I already thought of that but I don't really like that approach because you never know which package won't change the minor version number within an Ubuntu release. Do you know such package? Alternatively, I would be good if there is a package explicitly identifying the Ubuntu release such as `ubuntu-trusty_.....deb`.

Comment: @Stefan, updated answer

Answer (score 3):

Within a Debian package, there's no way to say "Allow installations on 14.04 only". That has to happen at the apt repository level (which I'll get to shortly later). The semi-exception to this is that because Trusty is newer than Precise, Trusty will have some library packages renamed (which, as long as the user's not using a PPA that provides these packages, will make them uninstallable) and will have newer versions of libraries, for which `dh-shlibdeps` *may* add a version requirement. Therefore, in both of these cases, the package will be uninstallable in Precise. Note that a package built for Precise *might* be able to be installed in Trusty.

As for the apt repository, packages do have a separate debian version number for each release. The format you describe could work, although using `~` is more common, partly because `~` is less than all other characters, and so if the user upgrades to a newer release (e.g. from Precise to Trusty), and the package is present in the official repos (with a version number of `1.0.0-3`, then the user will upgrade from `1.0.0-3~precise1` to `1.0.0-3`, even if you have a `1.0.0-3~trusty1`. This won't apply if you use any other character. I personally use something like `1.0.0-0ubuntu1~ppa1~precise1`; the `~ppa1` part is to make it less than any official Ubuntu package that might come in the future, and the `~precise1` part is to specify the release. Other PPA maintainers may use `1.0.0-3~12.04.1` or `1.0.0-3~14.04.1`, specifying the version number instead of the codename, which is guaranteed to be increasing (as long as Ubuntu version numbers don't reset).

Note that the binary packages have the same source package, so you would need to make sure your `.changes` file does not include the source package.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Relying on certain version numbers of a certain Ubuntu release seems a bit hacky to me. - Do you know how can I control the package file name. Because `dpkg-buildpackage` automatically chooses the name based on the control file but I was unable to add the distro name.

Comment: The package file names depend on the `debian/control` file and the `debian/changelog` file. The file naming convention is `binaryPackageName_binaryVersion.deb`. The `binaryVersion` part is the full version number at the top of `debian/changelog`. Therefore, if you have the distro name there (as part of the version itself), it should appear in the final package name.